# MariaDB - Should I add index to my table?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, query-performance

Recently I was checking my system logs and I noticed some of my queries are very slow.

I have a table that stores user activites. The table structure is `id (int), user (int), type (int), object (varchar), extra (mediumtext) and date (timestamp)`.

Also I only have index for `id (BTREE, unique)`.

I have performance issues for following query;

```
SELECT  DISTINCT object as usrobj
    from  ".MV15_PREFIX."useractivities
    WHERE  user='".$user_id."'
      and  type = '3'
    limit  0,1000000"
```

Question is, should I also index `user` same as `id`? What should be the best practise I should follow?

This table is actively used and has over 500k+ rows in it. And there are 2k~ concurrent users online average on site.

The reason I am asking this question is I am not really good at managing DB, and also I have slow query issue on another table which has proper indexes.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Side note:

**Result of mysqltuner**

**General recommendations:**

```
Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
```

**Variables to adjust:**

```
max_connections (> 768)
wait_timeout (< 28800)
interactive_timeout (< 28800)
join_buffer_size (> 64.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
```

(I will set `max_connections` > 768, not really sure about **timeouts** and as far I read topics/suggestions in Stackoverflow I think I shouldn't increase the size of `join_buffer_size` but I'd really appreciate getting feedback about these variables too.)

**EDIT - SHOW INDEX result;**

```
+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| ***_useractivities |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id          | A         |      434006 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| ***_useractivities |          1 | user_index      |            1 | user        | A         |       13151 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| ***_useractivities |          1 | user_type_index |            1 | user        | A         |       10585 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| ***_useractivities |          1 | user_type_index |            2 | type        | A         |       13562 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: All the tuner suggestions are irrelevant to the Question about indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these rules of thumb for PostgreSQL indexing apply to most SQL database management systems.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31517/1064

So, yes, you will probably benefit from an index on `user` and an index on `type`. You might benefit more from an index on the pair `user, type`.

You'll benefit from learning how to [read an execution plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html), too.

Comment: Thank you, lots of useful information on this link! One question, Indexing everyhing, i mean anything used by database will have side effects? Or should I index only when really necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "indexing everything". Every index increases the size of the database. Indexes make some `select` statements faster. They make some `insert`, `update`, and `delete` statements slower, because the dbms has to change the row *and* update the index. But, in this context, *faster* doesn't necessarily mean *fast*, and *slower* usually doesn't mean *slow*. Indexes aren't the only database tuning tool that database administrators have. Don't guess. Make a plan, measure, make changes, measure again.

Comment: @pelin Please consider posting A) your entire mysqltuner report, much of the information is useful (some recommendations should NOT be implemented and need more thought), B) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;  C) SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; and D)  results of EXPLAIN SELECT .......;  so we can see the execution plan.  Index ONLY when needed, including covering indexes - pair user, type - as suggested.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I have started testing the changes. So far not getting much of an improvement but understanding the importance of indexes. @WilsonHauck Explain Select really helmed me, I didn't know I could see whether it was using indexes or not. After adding the indexes Mike suggested, it's faster but not as expected.

Comment: @Pelin: Paste Wilson Hauck's suggestions into your question. (Output of SHOW CREATE TABLE, SHOW INDEX, EXPLAIN SELECT)

Comment: @pelin  Posting text results of SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; will probably reveal you still need a covering index pair for (user. type).  If missing, I will be able to give you the ALTER command.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added SHOW INDEX result to the question, it only had 1 index but as Mike suggested I added `user`, `type` and `user,type` indexes as BTREE. Not quite sure about Hash

Comment: @pelin We can now see you have the composite index for (user, type).  Cheers.  Please post results of   EXPLAIN SELECT .....(your query); and we still can not see results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;

Comment: @pelin Please post results of EXPLAIN SELECT .....(your query); and we still can not see results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;   Third time could be the charm needed to make this information visible.

Answer (score 0):

For *that* query, *either* of these is optimal:

```
INDEX(user, type)
INDEX(type, user)
```

Separate indexes (`INDEX(user), INDEX(type)`) is likely to be not nearly as good.

MySQL's InnoDB has only `BTree`, not `Hash`.  Anyway, BTree is essentially as good as Hash for 'point queries', and immensely better for 'range' queries.

Indexing [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Indexes help `SELECTs` and `UPDATEs`, sometimes a lot.  Use them.  The side effects are minor -- such as extra disk space used.